# Prevent Windows 7 from autologon

Tags: windows-7, autologon

I'm not able to use the shift key to override autologon on a Windows 7 x64. I try to install the hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977534 and I get the error "The update is not applicable to your computer.".

Any ideas?

Comment: In the Microsoft page which you mentioned, They told to install this Hotfix first https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2526967. Have you done?

Comment: They told "you must apply hotfix 2526967 AFTER you apply hotfix 977534". 
However, I install the hotfix 2526967 and things get weird. Now sometimes I prevent autologon, but not everytime. It seems strange.